# How do I code my servlet so it works nicely with Cloudfront Cache

Tags: java, servlets, caching, amazon-cloudfront

My servlet application is deployed to direct.albunack.net and there is a CloudFront cache at www.albunack.net.

The default page (index.jsp) is an (artist) search. Assuming for just a moment we are using direct.albunack.net when you enter search and submit the search goes to **direct.albunack.net/artist/search**. Everything under /artist maps to a servlet, this servlet does the search, if it finds only one result it then does a redirect to direct.albunack.net/artist/*artistid*  - this uses the same servlet to construct a page for that artist and return it.

If instead it finds multiple results it then forwards results back to index.jsp but displaying the multiple results, if user then clicks on one of these results they are again redirected to direct.albunack.net/artist/*artistid*

So far so good, the problem occurs when I use **www.albunack.net**. The Cloudfront default (*) behaviour is to cache all requests, not forward headers ectera. But we add another behaviour for the **/artist/search** path so that it doesn't cache the actual search.

When it finds multiple results it redirects to **http://www.albunack.net/index.jsp** and then subsequently clicking on one of the choices redirects to http://www.albunack.net/artist/*artistid*.

But the problem I have (I think) is that because the search delegates down to **direct.albunack.net** when there is only one choice it redirects to http://**direct**.albunack.net/artist/artistid bypassing the cache and exposing our direct interface.

So how do I code this, if i actually hardcode the complete path including server then its not going to work when running locally, what is the right way.

**Servlet code extract:**

```
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(artistName))
{
    //Look up artist for that id
    MusicBrainzSearchArtist mbArtistSearch = new MusicBrainzSearchArtist();
    List<Artist> mbArtists = mbArtistSearch.queryByArtistName(artistName);

    if (mbArtists.size() == 0)
    {
        request.setAttribute(ERROR, InfoMessage.MSG_NO_RESULTS_FOUND.getMsg(artistName));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
    else if (mbArtists.size() == 1)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/artist/" + mbArtists.get(0).getId());
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        request.setAttribute(ERROR, InfoMessage.MSG_MULTIPLE_RESULTS_FOUND.getMsg(artistName));
        request.setAttribute("results", mbArtists);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Ive modified

```
 response.sendRedirect("/artist/" + mbArtists.get(0).getId());
```

to

```
response.sendRedirect(getRedirectServePath(request) + "/artist/" + mbArtists.get(0).getId());

 public String getRedirectServerPath(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort();
    }
```

and that works, but this seems ever so hacky and Im not sure quite sure why it works as I thought request.getServerName() would return direct.albunack.net or is it www.albunack.net because getServerName() returns the name of the original entry point onto the server but without it the path /artist will resolve the current server when doing a redirect ?

Comment: Any reason you can't do relative redirect? E.g. don't specify the domain name? I'm not familiar with framework you are using, but this is the right approach if you want to access site from multiple domain names (as in your case).

Comment: In the original code I am doing relative redirect arent i (response.sendRedirect("/artist/" + mbArtists.get(0).getId());) and that did not work as described.

Comment: As a side note, in your new code I would definitely not hard code to http. You can use request.getScheme() instead.

Comment: @rock-fall, thanks good point -(but should I have to do this at all)

Comment: I think you are on the right path and have no other option from a coding perspective. You should look for some configuration on the cloud front cache if you could specify a url pattern that should be cached so that the redirect does not fall through to your direct interface.

Comment: Don't worry, Paul, this is no hack, this is "best practice"! You should also adapt rock-fall's hint, and use only *this* type of redirect ...in a "layered environment". (So you will redirect always to (relativley) where the request came from, except you have opposite intents (e.g. redirecting to a dedicated servlet))

Comment: okay I ve kept as is plus using getSchema()

Comment: Hmm, I havent changed  getRedirectServerPath() method yet a new deployment of may application and the direct problem has reocurred, unsure what has changed to cause this.

Comment: Cloudfront is technology agnostic, so you should be able to implement these patterns in a servlet model: http://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/CloudFront-design-patterns-and-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

Add something unique to the request (like timestamp to the url) and it will be not cached any more.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think youve understood the question, the problem was that the direct url was being exposed.

Comment: Paul Taylor, the fact that 'url was being exposed' wasn't quite clear at the question.